# Send user to page

Tags: php

I am using a PHP script to send data to my database.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
  session_start(); 
  $correct = true;

  $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'] ;
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'] ;

  if($correct){
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', '');

    $query = "INSERT INTO names(user_id, firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id'], $firstname, $lastname));

    header('Location: ../names.php');
  }
  else
  {
    echo  "<p>Error</p>";
  }
?>
```

The script is working fine but after the SQL statement is executed I want to send the user to a page where the user can see the data he entered.

In the current state the script is sending the user to `names.php`. I want to send the user to `names.php?id=8`.

The `id` column is auto increment.

Does someone know how I can send the user to the `id` of the executed statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get last inserted id by this,

```
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

and then you can pass it to `header` method. Like below,

```
header('Location: ../names.php?id='.$id);
```

Comment: You forgot a `.` for string concatenation... :)

Answer (score 3):

after your excecute do:

```
header('Location: ../names.php?id='.$db->lastInsertId);
```

[PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: I guess you meant `header('Location: ../names.php?id=' . $db->lastInsertId);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do another query for Select id from table where user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'] after Insert statement.

Then You can use result on your link names.php?id=[result from Select]